# Carrierwave - How to reference a model's image from a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, carrierwave

I have a User model and a Project model. The User model has a PhotoUploader as a carrierwave uploader, and the Project model has a LogoUploader as a carrierwave uploader.

I also have a Poster model that references a User or a Project. With this Poster I can make a post with an User or a Project, in the same way (showing a name, a description and a **image**).

The problem is that I want to reference a photo from an User or a logo from a Project, using a string attribute like "image", that is an Uploader object from carrierwave.

**I don't want to duplicate images.**

How can I do this? Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: remind me of ducktyping .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Polymorphic Association** is what you need. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations
http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised

**models/media.rb**

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :mediable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name
  has_many :medias, as: :mediable
end
```

**models/project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name
  has_many :medias, as: :mediable
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources :medias
end

resources :projects do
  resources :medias
end
```

when you save a media to user, you'll create a new media row:

```
id   mediable_type   mediable_id    some_other_field
 1       User             1           something here
```

then you can call `current_user.medias`

Comment: I could use polymorphism, but I want a different carrierwave uploader for User and for Project, that is the problem. I can't merge the two uploaders into a single model like Media.